# Horizontal box plots in matplotlib/Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

#### Bar plots:

`matplotlib` offers the function [`bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) and [`barh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.barh) to do **vertical** and **horizontal** bar plots.

#### Box plots:

`matplotlib` also offers the function [`boxplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=boxplot#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) to do **vertical** box plots.

And [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) offers [its own function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) for **vertical** box plots.

But is there any way in matplotlib or Pandas to get a **horizontal** box plot?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

matplotlib's `boxplot(..., vert=False)` makes horizontal box plots.
The keyword parameter `vert=False` can also be passed to `DataFrame.boxplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
x = [[1.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.5],
     [1.1, 2.2, 2.9, 5.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=['Age of pregnant women', 'Age of pregnant men'])

df.T.boxplot(vert=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
plt.show()
```

### [image]

I see from the comment (below) that the motivation for making a horizontal box plot is that the labels are rather long. Another option in that case might be to rotate the xticklabels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
x = [[1.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.5],
     [1.1, 2.2, 2.9, 5.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=['Age of pregnant women', 'Age of pregnant men'])

df.T.boxplot()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Strangely my labels for xticks are not fitting in the figure when I do this (which is precisely the reason why I wanted to use horizontal box plots). The longest xtick reads something like `"Age of pregnant women"`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina try adding `plt.tight_layout()` before plotting.

Comment: @unutbu what's the relationship between df and plt ... how plt know about the dataframe

Comment: @AndreaMoro: Pandas is built on top of `NumPy` and `Matplotlib`. `df` is a Pandas DataFrame. It's `boxplot` method calls matplotlib functions to build the boxplot.  Under the hood, `df.boxplot` calls `plt.boxplot`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Is there a  way to switch `age...women` with `age...men` in the horizontal version? Meaning `age...men` is above `age ... women`. I created a plot with a dozen of boxes. In the vertical view, they are sorted in the way I want them to, but when I flip them to horizontal, the sorting becomes mixed up. I would've expected that the left box becomes the uppermost one, which is not the case.

Answer (score 9):

```
vert=False stands # for "no vertical"
```

Use by='categorical_feature name' to make box for every level
    plt.tight_layout() # kills any overlapping plots (not always)
Matplotlib and Pandas are really easy when you master them and you can do powerful plots using them.

Answer (score 5):

matplotlib has a **vert** property which is set to True by default. Change it to **False**

```
plt.boxplot(df["feature"], vert=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with this example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
plt.xlabel("value")
plt.ylabel("value")

plt.boxplot(a,vert=False)
plt.show()
```