# How to make boxplots with python ggplot package

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying out and really liking the python port of ggplot (http://ggplot.yhathq.com/)

I want to make some boxplots of data but can't figure out how to do it, hoping someone could help.

Here is sample code:

```
#Create pandas dataframe with random number data and labels 'A', 'B'
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,40)).transpose()
labels = np.repeat(['A','B'],20)
data['labels']=labels
data.columns = ['vals','labels']
```

Output

```
   vals          labels
0 -0.685582      A
1 -0.332966      A
2  0.766283      A
3  1.751677      A
4  1.613434      A
```

Now I try

```
ggplot(data,aes(x='labels',y='vals')) + geom_boxplot()
```

and I get the error

```
<repr(<ggplot.ggplot.ggplot at 0x7f204dbb4810>) failed: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type>
```

After a bit of searching I think the problem is with the labels being string valued categorical data, but I'm not sure how to get ggplot to recognize this on the x axis

Answer (score 5):

I don't think using the x axis to display the labels is currently possible with python `ggplot`. I can create the separate boxplots using an `x='vals',y='labels'` but I cannot adjust the x axis.

```
from ggplot import ggplot, aes, geom_boxplot

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,40)).transpose()
labels = np.repeat(['A','B'],20)
data['labels']=labels
data.columns = ['vals','labels']

ggplot(data, aes(x='vals', y='labels')) + geom_boxplot()
```

Looking at the code for `geom_boxplot` it doesn't seem possible to adjust what the axis map to: [geom_boxplot.py](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/blob/fa84a244ee2e89763723b06b00510481d0001409/ggplot/geoms/geom_boxplot.py#L12)

To get around that limitation I would usually use `coord_flip` in R but it seems that `coord_flip` is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/239).

That said, since ggplot wraps matplotlib you could create a new `geom_boxplot` which calls the `matplotlib` with `vert=True` instead of `vert=False` as seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500011/horizontal-box-plots-in-matplotlib-pandas).

I hope this information is helpful

Comment: Great thanks @erik-e, will use horizontal boxplot for now and have a go at extending the geom_boxplot when I got time. Would upvote your answer, but don't have enough cred